# Reverse Geocoding Responses randomly in php

Tags: php, google-maps

I have tried google reverse geocode.Following function called in for loop multiple times...this Works randomly...Sometimes response address perfectly..sometimes no response got...What is the problem here...

```
function reversegeo($ilatt,$ilonn)
{

$url1='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$ilatt.','.$ilonn.'&sensor=false';
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.mywebsiteurl.com/Trackfiles/report.php');
$body1 = curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
$json1 = json_decode($body1);
$add=$json1->results[0]->formatted_address;
return $add;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting the server too often, or too fast. Add some delays in there with `sleep()`.

Also when you say "no response got" you need to be more specific. Google will give an error code if you are hitting it too often, it won't just be nothing.

Instead of:

```
$body1 = curl_exec($ch1);
```

Do:

```
if(($body1 = curl_exec($ch1)) === false) {
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: yes..thank you... I got following error...Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'maps.googleapis.com'.....Can i use sleep function to solve this..or some other way to solve this?

Comment: Couldn't resolve host? That's a problem with your internet connection, nothing to do with google. Where are you running this? Windows? Linux? On a hosted server?

Comment: Yes..This PHP runs on our Domain in yahoo small business server...What is the problem in our domain...

Comment: So your ISP is yahoo? You're going to have to ask them, we can't help you here for an error like that.

Comment: Thank You..But sometimes i got OVERQUERY_LIMIT error...could i know number of request per minute in google Reverse Geocoding webservice or any other restrictions?...

Comment: 2,500 per day. See: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits